# Bitbucket CodeDeploy integration: This app is hidden from public view because it no longer meets the requirements for Atlassian Marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy(continuous deployment) my bitbucket repository using AWS CodeDeploy and following the blog by aws https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/announcing-atlassian-bitbucket-support-for-aws-codedeploy/

While adding AWS CodeDeploy plugin to BitBucket, it shows message in Bitbucket marketplace
`This app is hidden from public view because it no longer meets the requirements for Atlassian Marketplace.`

Is there any other plugin which has replaced it or bitbucket doesn't supports AWS CodeDeploy anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very old document and probably the plugin is not maintained anymore. This article on Atlassian site seems more relevant and up-to-date but it uses Atlassian 'Pipeline' product:

- Deploy to AWS with CodeDeploy: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-aws-with-codedeploy-976773337.html

Second option is using AWS CodePipeline to fetch BitBucket code and Deploy using CodeDeploy deploy action. This tutorial will be helpful (replace CodeCommit with BitBucket):

- Tutorial: Create a Simple Pipeline (CodeCommit Repository)  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html